# OracleHelper: How to read data from Oracle OUT SYS_REFCURSOR SProc parameter into a dataset?

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio, odp.net, sys-refcursor

I get following error when I try to pass the result from store procedure to the dataset. The OracleHelper class is similar to SqlHelper, just that it is referencing Oracle.

I am using ODP.NET managed driver.

I do have sample data in the ACCOUNTS table.

Error:

```
ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:

PLS-00306: wrong number or types of arguments in call to 'GET_ACCOUNT_DETAILSV2'

ORA-06550: line 1, column 7:
```

c#:

```
public DataSet GetUserData(string PHONE_NUMBER)
    {
        return (DataSet)OracleHelper.ExecuteDataset(GetConnectionString(), "GET_ACCOUNT_DETAILSV2", PHONE_NUMBER);); 
    }
```

Store procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE GET_ACCOUNT_DETAILSV2 (
   PHONE_NUMBER   IN ACCOUNTS.PHONE%TYPE,
   o_rc     OUT         SYS_REFCURSOR)
IS
BEGIN
      OPEN o_rc FOR
         SELECT ID,
                STATUS,
                EMAIL
           FROM ACCOUNTS
          WHERE PHONE = PHONE_NUMBER;
END GET_ACCOUNT_DETAILSV2;
/
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Is phone_number a user defined type? If so you may want to use a scalar type (eg VARCHAR2) to make things simpler. Also you don't show how the bind variable is being set up. How does your OracleHelper class know what bind type to use for the parameter value? You need to find out what type ODP.NET is using to bind  and also what type phone_number is in the PL/SQL and find out why they are not compatible.Perhaps your OracleHelper is failing to bind at all.

Comment: I just noticed that you did not bind the OUT SYS_REFCURSOR. That is probably your problem. You have two paramaters in your Sproc but are only telling ExecuteDataset about one of them. How does it know it needs to bind to the OUT parameter? It most likely does not and is not, hence the error.

Comment: The key thing here is that Oracle and SQL Server handle cursors very differently. SQL Server returns them without using bind variables, where Oracle requires bind variables. That means that you are now using a helper class based on SQL Server techniques to do something unique to Oracle. I am sure that this is all spelled out in the OracleHelper documentation/help forums since this should be a very common problem with this helper class.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection("User Id=marketing;Password=SECRET;Data Source=dashworks-db"))
        {
            conn.Open();
            using (OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("GET_ACCOUNT_DETAILSV2", conn))
            {
                cmd.BindByName = true;
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("PHONE_NUMBER", "416-123-4567");
                cmd.Parameters.Add("o_rc", OracleDbType.RefCursor, ParameterDirection.Output);
                using (OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd))
                {
                    DataSet ds = new DataSet("result");
                    ds.Locale = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
                    adapter.Fill(ds);
                }
            }
        }
```